# How to use snowflake variables to insert data into a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cloud, session-variables

I'm trying to generalize a snowflake script with variables and currently stuck on how to use variables as column names to insert data into the table.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

Source table variables

```
set schem_name = 'schema';
set table_name = 'destination';
set s_var1 = 'source_col_1';
set s_var2 = 'source_col_2';
```

destination table variables

```
set d_var1 = 'dest_col_1';
set d_var2 = 'dest_col_2';
```

Now trying to insert into destination table

```
use schema identifier($schema_name);
```

below select statement works without issue.

```
select identifier($s_var1), identifier($s_var2)
from identifier($table_name);
```

But when trying to insert I keep getting errors.
This is what I tried.

```
insert into destination_table (identifier($d_var1), identifier($d_var2))
select identifier($s_var1), identifier($s_var2)
from identifier($table_name);
```

Comment: Your INSERT statement is not giving the name of the table you are inserting to. It should be of the format : INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, ..) SELECT col1, col2 …

Comment: @NickW Thank you for pointing this out. It's a mistake from my end. I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: What errors are you getting? If you look at QUERY_HISTORY does it show your query with some/all of the variables converted to actual values? If it does, what does that query look like?

Comment: @NickW yes variables are converted without issues. This is the error I'm getting **SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 77 unexpected '('. syntax error line 1 at position 78 unexpected '$prf_segment'. syntax error line 1 at position 91 unexpected ')'.***. Pasting the code for reference -  `insert into common_user.model_predictions(identifier($prf_segment))
select identifier($mdl_segment) from identifier($table_name)`